# Visual Studio Localhost Redirect Problem Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, localhost

I have a test site running on Visual Studio 2008. When I try to debug and it opens up the browser through localhost, I can this error"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." 
However, when I open the site through IIS, it works fine.

**Things I've Tried:**

Clearing Cookies

Answer (score 0):

in firefox you might be able to clear your cookies and authenticated session list.  Last time this happened to me it was because i was authenticated with the wrong credentials.  One page thought i was authenticated, the other knew i wasnt and i was being bounced back and forth.

Comment: tried the cookies. I think it's something w/ visual studio because it works fine if I load the site through IIS

Answer (score 0):

Need more info here.  Are you using Forms authentication?  Is it possible your Login page is set incorrectly?  Have you tried just setting Visual Studio to debug using IIS?  Does that work OK?  What about debugging with IE?  Same behavior?

I believe the built-in development web server does not support all forms of authentication.